# search embeded webpage source in vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net

I wrote a program that includes an embedded web browser that loads a website which have a changing part (the part changes about 2 times a week and it have no regular timing pattern) that I want to search for a particular part in the opened webpage source code after refreshing the webpage in a specified time interval.

I found many things similar to my question but this is what I want and those questions doesn't have:

- search **embedded** webpage source (they searching the webpage without embedding, and I had to embed it because I had to login before I see the particular page)

so this is the procedure I'm trying to do:

> 1- open a website in embedded web browser
>
> 2- after user logged in, with a press of button in program, it hides the embedded
>   web browser and start to refresh the page in a time interval (like
>   every minute) and search if the particular code changed in the source of
>   that opened webpage

any other/better Ideas appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change to C# and I found what I was looking for:

```
string webPageSource = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
```

That gave me the source of web page opened in *webBrowser1* control.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago I wrote an app to reintegrate forum posts from several pages into one and I struggled with the login issue too and thought it was only possible using an embedded browser. As it turns out, it's possible to use System.Net in .NET to handle web pages that need a login as you can pull the cookies out and keep them on hand. I would suggest you do that and move away from the embedded browser.

Unfortunately I wrote the code in C# originally, but as it's .NET and is mostly classes-based, it shouldn't be too difficult to port over.

**The Basic Principle**

Find out what information is included in the POST when you login, which you can do in Chrome with developer mode on (F12). Convert that to a byteArray, POST it to the page, store the cookies and make another call with the cookie data later on. You will need a class variable to hold the cookies.

**Code:**

```
private void Login()
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&autologin=on&login=Log+in"); // Found by investigation

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("yourURL");
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
        {
            // Well done, your login has been accepted
            loginDone = true;
            cookies = request.CookieContainer;
        }
        else
        {
            // If at first you don't succeed...
        }

        response.Close();
    }

private string GetResponseHTML(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        // Add cookies from Login()
        request.CookieContainer = cookies; 

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        string sResponse = "";
        StreamReader reader = null;
        if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            sResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }
        response.Close();

        return sResponse;
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but the website have two separate pages to get username and password. is that works on pages like that too?

Comment: HttpWebRequest has a lot of options for browser communication. If you investigate how the pages communicate and mirror that with System.Net then you should be able to get it working.

Comment: do you have any social app so we can chat? I'm starting to have some problems with c# and i need to get it to somewhere today?

Comment: I'm still at work and the network is locked down pretty tight.

Comment: I tried your code, some questions: when loginDone will use? why is my login page fails to login? I found the communicate way: "password="+password+"&level=2&username="+username+"&name=LOGIN" is it seems correct?

Comment: The loginDone was to communicate back to the original app that it didn't need to login again - it was to do with the specific way I needed it to run - so you can get rid of loginDone if you need to. Your login string looks good.

Comment: so why is it always fails? at the first page it sends username and at the second page it sends username and password, is it because of that?